# Using OAuth2, how can I prevent Spring Security from calling a userinfo server during login?

Tags: spring-boot, oauth, userinfo

I am using PingFederate from PingIdentity (https://www.pingidentity.com/en.html) as my SSO provider.  Ping encodes the typical user info (name, email, etc...) in the JWT that is returned from the token endpoint, thus there is no userinfo endpoint to connect with.

When I setup Spring Boot to authenticate with Ping, all works well until Spring Boot looks for a userinfo endpoint.  Is there a way to tell Spring Security to skip the call to the userinfo endpoint?

I have read all of the documentation that I can find (https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/reactive/oauth2/login/advanced.html) and there does not seem to be a setting that will disable the dependency on a call to a userinfo endpoint, short of implementing a custom ReactiveOAuth2UserService.

Comment: And your Spring dependencies, properties and Java configuration are...